# Home Custom Menu Link not Working

Tags: navigation, menus

I'm trying to have the menu link per default when using my custom menus, and in my `functions.php` document I have this:

```
function home_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'home_page_menu_args' );
```

The thing is, in the custom menu options > pages I have this: "No items." So not sure what's going on, it was working in other websites but not in this one, any idea?

Comment: Do you have any pages created?

Comment: I just created some pages and they appeared normally, still nothing about the home page

Comment: Is `wp_nav_menu()` displaying a custom nav menu, or a fallback menu? If a fallback menu, is it `wp_page_menu()`, or a custom fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll assume that you have custom nav menus properly configured:

1. `register_nav_menus()` in `functions.php`, to define `theme_location` values
2. `wp_nav_menu()` calls in the template, with `theme_location` called in the args array
3. Custom nav menus defined in the admin
4. Custom nav menu(s) assigned to Theme Locations

If that's the case, then the issue is that you're using the wrong filter. The [`wp_page_menu_args` filter is applied](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L898) inside of [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), which is the default callback for `wp_nav_menu()` when no menu is assigned to the indicated `theme_location`.

The output of [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) applies its own filter: [`wp_nav_menu_args`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L155). So you'll need to hook your callback into that filter as well:

```
function home_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'home_page_menu_args' );
// Hook into wp_nav_menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'home_page_menu_args' );
```

That way, the `show_home` arg will return true for both `wp_page_menu()` output and for `wp_nav_menu()` output.

Be careful with `wp_nav_menu()`, though; if the user adds a home link to the custom menu, then *two* home page links will be displayed in the rendered menu.